# MMA 11.2. Input Assistant not working

Tags: version-11.2

Why not work  [Input Assistant](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UsingTheInputAssistant.html)?

[image]

I have a Windows 10, and Wolfram *Mathematica* 11.2,

I reinstalled *W.M* but there is a same problem...

Comment: Had the same issue on a Linux machine yesterday. Deleting the .Mathematica directory fixed it for me . But then you have to type in the activation key again. Unfortunately I don't now where that directory is located on a Windows machine.

Comment: I have the same issue on my mac. Do you happen to know how to solve this? @Armin

Comment: @407Peezy Deleting the $UserBaseDirectory fixed it for me. The default locations are: Window: "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica" on Mac: Mac OS X ~/Library/Mathematica (see: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConfigurationFiles.html)

Comment: @Armin works like a charm! Thx

Comment: For me it dose not work. Can you help me ? I have a Mac OS High Sierra

Comment: @AndreaPalladino Try `RenameDirectory[#, #<>"old"]&@$UserBaseDirectory` and restart MMA.